# Does partitions need to be physically neighbor to combined

Tags: partitioning, drive

Back in the day i had dual boot(windows10) so i have a few NTFS partitions in my drive, but i deleted Windows long ago still not combined these part of my drives. I mount NTFS style but its not ideal. I want to combined some of NTFS areas to Linux file system.

Here's my current situation with gParted.

I can delete /sda2 its currently fully empty. But can deleting /sda2 make it combine with /ext4 ?

[image]

Comment: Note that Linux Mint is not an official Ubuntu flavour, but in this case I'm 99% sure the answer is the same. In the future, please ask on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, once you delete sda2, you have two options for expanding partitions into the space it leaves behind

1. sda3 (extended) then sda5 (ext4 within extended)

   - I assume this is what you want.
2. sda1 (ext4)

See [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) for how